# Exception_Access_Violation --- command line render always quits

Tags: rendering, error, command-line

Recently i had a new CPU put into my system, i9 from i7. Since then i've been getting this error always when i do command line renders.. it usually goes for a while then stops. Anyone have a clue what could be happening? Drivers are all up to date.

PC has 1000 watt power supply. 64gigs of ram and i have a 4090 gpu.

[image]